# Can you project on an orthogonal basis for a multipartite system using only local measurements and classical communication?

Tags: measurement, communication, projection-operator, locc-operation, classical-communication

Say Alice possesses one qubit, and Bob two, and that the joint state is $|\psi_{A, B_1, B_2}\rangle = \alpha|n_1\rangle + \beta |n_2\rangle$, where $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$ are orthonormal basis states for the combined Hilbert space. If you have access to all qubits, there obviously is a measurement which projects on the basis that includes $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$.

However, what if you only allow Alice and Bob to do local measurements on their qubits? Then, I assume that Bob would need to send at least one classical bit to Alice for a joint measurement to be possible. Do they also need local quantum registers? Can we say anything about when such a joint measurement is possible?

Perhaps a concrete example would be: Let's say Alice and Bob share the state $|\psi_{A, B_1, B_2}\rangle = \alpha|n_1\rangle + \beta |n_2\rangle$. Is it possible, using only LOCC, to end up in the joint state $|n_1\rangle$ with probability $|\alpha|^2$, and in $|n_2\rangle$ with probability $|\beta|^2$, so that afterwards both parties know what the shared state is?

I assume that the precise implementation of such a measurement will depend on the states $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$, but is there a general rule for when such a joint measurement is possible?

---

Crossposted to ph.se: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782508/can-you-project-on-an-orthogonal-basis-for-a-multipartite-quantum-system-using-o

Comment: The answer is probably no if $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$ are entangled states

Comment: Yes, that might very well be. The counterexample offered here is also based on that : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782508/can-you-project-on-an-orthogonal-basis-for-a-multipartite-quantum-system-using-o